# VSCode only searching within files, not on actual filename

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

When I search using the Search View, my results only contain files that have that pattern within the body of the file, rather than also including files with that filename.
I've activated the "search only in open editors" toggle button, so it isn't that causing the issue.
I know the files are there, as I can browse for them manually, or find them using "locate" in the terminal.
Would rebuilding the search index resolve this?  And how would I do that, if so?
I've checked all the search related settings within the VSCode preferences also.
"Files to include" path is correctly set to ./ but even when searching on the entire root (/) the files cannot be found.

Comment: Search in the file *list* area if you want to search in file*names*. Or just use the Ctrl+P to open a file by name.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks.  I forgot about Cntrl-P!  That works.  But in the normal search in the left hand bar, it used to come up with actual filenames as well as content within files.  At least I have the Cntrl-P as a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of VS Code's Search View ever searching for files by name. It searches for file *contents*.

If you want to search for files by name, you can use <kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in the Explorer View, or use Quick Open (bound by default to <kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I think this is a user error on my part - I mistakenly thought it also returned filename results in that search, but apparently not.
I think I'll use the cmd/P option from hereon.